# Scala: How to create a simple nested JSON object

Tags: json, scala, gson

In Scala I want to create a JSON Object or JSON String where the result would be something similar to this (i.e. a relatively basic nested JSON):

```
{
   "info":{
      "info1":"1234",
      "info2":"123456",
      "info3":false
   },
   "x":[
      {
         "x1_info":10,
         "x2_info":"abcde"
      }
   ],
   "y":[
      {
         "y1_info":"28732",
         "y2_info":"defghi",
         "y3_info":"1261",
         "y_extra_info":[
            {
               "Id":"543890",
               "ye1":"asdfg",
               "ye2":"BOOLEAN",
               "ye3":false,
               "ye4":true,
               "ye5":true,
               "ye6":0,
               "ye7":396387
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I plan to use this object in tests so ideally I can set the information inside the JSON object to whatever I want (I don't plan on sourcing the info for the JSON object from a separate file). I tried the following where I created a Map of the information I want in my JSON object and then tried converting it to json using gson:

```
val myInfo = Map(
      "info" -> Map("info1" -> "1234",
        "info2" -> "123456",
        "info3" -> "false"),
      "x" -> Map("x1_info" -> 10,
            "x2_info" -> "abcde"),
      "y" -> Map("y1_info" -> "28732",
            "y2_info" -> "defghi",
            "y3_info" -> "1261",
        "y_extra_info"-> Map("Id" -> "543890",
          "ye1" -> "asdfg",
          "ye2" -> "BOOLEAN",
          "ye3" -> false,
          "ye4" -> true,
          "ye5" -> true,
          "ye6" -> 0,
          "ye7" -> 396387
        )
      )
    )
val gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting.create
print(gson.toJson(myInfo))
```

However though it produces JSON correctly does not produce the JSON in the structure I have above but instead structures it like so:

```
{
  "key1": "info",
  "value1": {
    "key1": "info1",
    "value1": "1234",
    "key2": "info2",
    "value2": "123456",
...(etc)...
```

I have figured out an inelegant way of achieving what I want by creating a string containing the JSON I expect and then parsing as JSON (but I assume there is a better way)

```
val jsonString = "{\"info\":{\"info1\":\"1234\", \"info2\":\"123456\", " +
      "\"info3\":false}," +
      "\"x\":[{ \"x1_info\":10,\"x2_info\":\"abcde\"}]," +
      "\"y\":[{\"y1_info\":\"28732\",\"y2_info\":\"defghi\",\"y3_info\":\"1261\", " +
      "\"y_extra_info\":[{" +
      "\"Id\":\"543890\",\"ye1\":\"asdfg\"," +
      "\"ye2\":\"BOOLEAN\",\"ye3\":false,\"ye4\":true," +
      "\"ye5\":true,\"ye6\":0,\"ye7\":396387}]}]}"
```

I'm relatively new to Scala so perhaps using a Map or writing it all out as a string is not the best or most "Scala way"?

Is there an easy way to create such a JSON object using preferable either gson or spray or otherwise by some other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there's no good reason to use GSON with Scala, as GSON is Java-based and doesn't really know how to deal with Scala collections.  In this case, it doesn't know how to deal with the key-value-ness of a Scala `Map` and instead (most likely due to reflection) just leaks the implementation detail of the default Scala `Map` being customized for the cases where the size is less than 4.

JSON libraries which are native to Scala (e.g. circe, play-json, spray-json, etc.) do what you expect for `String`-keyed `Map`s.  They also have built-in support for directly handling `case class`es in Scala, e.g. for

```
case class Foo(id: String, code: Int, notes: String)

val foo = Foo("fooId", 42, "this is a very important foo!")
```

will serialize as something like (ignoring possible differences around pretty-printing and field ordering)

```
{ "id": "fooId", "code": 42, "notes": "this is a very important foo!" }
```

If there's a hard project requirement that you must use GSON, I believe it does understand Java's collections, so you could convert a Scala `Map` to a `java.util.Map` by using the conversions in `CollectionConverters` (in 2.13, it's in the `scala.jdk` package; in earlier versions, it should be in `scala.collection`).  I'm not going to elaborate on this, because my very strong opinion is that in a Scala codebase, it's best to use a native-to-Scala JSON library.